# TeamCity Automatic Checkout Directory (work directory) Cleaning

Tags: teamcity

Each clean checkout TeamCity creates `<Agent Work Directory>/<VCS settings hash code>` directory for the build.
And it is feasible to [Automatic Checkout Directory Cleaning](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD65/Build+Checkout+Directory#BuildCheckoutDirectory-EnsuringFreeDiskSpaceBeforetheBuild) where one could specify rules to clean up old build directories.

How could I tune agent to clean old build directory just after new one is created, ai not to maintain build history in work directory at all?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Your answer is right in your question! ;)

The section [Automatic Checkout Directory Cleaning](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD65/Build+Checkout+Directory) notes:

> The time frame for automatic directory expiration can be changed by specifying new value  (in hours) by either of the following ways:
>
> - 'system.teamcity.agent.build.checkoutDir.expireHours' agent property in the buildAgent.properties file;
> - 'system.teamcity.build.checkoutDir.expireHours' Build Configuration property
>
> **Setting the property to "0" will cause deleting the checkout directories right after the build finish.**

Comment: I want to delete <VCS settings hash code> directory ONLY if new one is created (for example in case of "Enforce clean checkout"), not after each build.